# How to group by, count if (or sum if) on new columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How to group by, count if (or sum if) and have the results in individual new columns in pandas dataframe?

for example, I have the data in this format.

| Date | animal |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | dog |
| 2021-01-01 | dog |
| 2021-01-02 | cat |
| 2021-01-02 | dog |
| 2021-01-03 | mouse |
| 2021-01-03 | dog |
| 2021-01-03 | cat |

in sql i would do something like this:

```
select date, sum(if(animal="dog",1,0) as dog, sum(if(animal="cat",1,0) as cat, sum(if(animal="mouse",1,0) as mouse
```

to get the desired result:

| Date | dog | cat | mouse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-02 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-01-03 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

1. TRY `pivot_table` to get the required.
2. Use rename_axis to remove the axis name.
3. Finally reset the index.

```
df = (
    df.reset_index()
    .pivot_table(
        index='Date',
        columns='animal',
        values='index',
        aggfunc='count',
        fill_value=0)
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
         Date  cat  dog  mouse
0  2021-01-01    0    2      0
1  2021-01-02    1    1      0
2  2021-01-03    1    1      1
```